# PHP on VirtualHost not working but works on default site

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd

I have a apache Server version: Apache/2.4.46 on Amazon Linux 2. PHP is working well on port 443.  I added another virtualhost on port 81. PHP does not work on this port.

Config:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName "www.mspvl.in"
    ServerAlias "mspvl.in"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mspvl.in [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mspvl.in
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin"
    ServerName "www.test.in"
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/vhost81_error_log
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.in/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.in/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

and ...

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin">
    Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin">
    Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
   TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

When I access ordinary html files via https://www.test.in:81/test.html, it works. But https://www.test.in:81/test.php produces a 403 Forbidden error.

File permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user apache       52 Apr 29 08:09 test.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ec2-user apache       82 Apr 29 08:49 test.php
```

Log file : ssl_access_log:

```
117.232.103.170 - - [29/Apr/2021:17:21:07 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
117.232.103.170 - - [29/Apr/2021:17:21:07 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 22486 "https://www.test.in:81/test.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
117.232.103.170 - - [29/Apr/2021:17:21:27 +0000] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
```

Log file vhost81_error_log:

```
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.128643 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 30312] [client 117.232.103.170:49793] AH01964: Connection to child 2 established (server www.test.in:443)
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.128794 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 30312] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2353): [client 117.232.103.170:49793] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername www.test.in found
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.128807 2021] [core:debug] [pid 30312] protocol.c(2341): [client 117.232.103.170:49793] AH03155: select protocol from h2,h2c,http/1.1, choices=h2,http/1.1 for server www.test.in
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.128812 2021] [core:debug] [pid 30312] protocol.c(2386): [client 117.232.103.170:49793] AH03156: select protocol, proposals=http/1.1 preferences=h2,h2c,http/1.1 configured=h2,h2c,http/1.1
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.128815 2021] [core:debug] [pid 30312] protocol.c(2404): [client 117.232.103.170:49793] AH03157: selected protocol=http/1.1
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.129063 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 30355] [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH01964: Connection to child 6 established (server www.test.in:443)
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.129158 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 30355] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2353): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername www.test.in found
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.129168 2021] [core:debug] [pid 30355] protocol.c(2341): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH03155: select protocol from h2,h2c,http/1.1, choices=h2,http/1.1 for server www.test.in
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.129172 2021] [core:debug] [pid 30355] protocol.c(2386): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH03156: select protocol, proposals=http/1.1 preferences=h2,h2c,http/1.1 configured=h2,h2c,http/1.1
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.129175 2021] [core:debug] [pid 30355] protocol.c(2404): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH03157: selected protocol=http/1.1
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.169292 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 30312] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2236): [client 117.232.103.170:49793] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.169657 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 30355] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2236): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.169832 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 30355] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 6 (server www.test.in:443)
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.170097 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 30355] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.170103 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 30355] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.170131 2021] [headers:debug] [pid 30355] mod_headers.c(900): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.347851 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 30355] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH02034: Subsequent (No.2) HTTPS request received for child 6 (server www.test.in:443), referer: https://www.test.in:81/test.php
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.348136 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 30355] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://www.test.in:81/test.php
[Thu Apr 29 17:21:07.348141 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 30355] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 117.232.103.170:24820] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://www.test.in:81/test.php
```

Please help.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, since this isn't your entire config. Any important differences from the virtual host that works on port 80? Are you sure this virtual host is the one being used? Try turning up LogLevel to at least trace3, or maybe higher to debug the access logic.

Comment: You checked some of the file permissions. Did you check the directory permissions?

Comment: `drwxrwxr-x 12 ec2-user ec2-user   4096 Apr 29 08:09 phpMyAdmin`

Comment: @AndrewSchulman , I have added more parts of the config, log with debug too